# How add table name prefix to all table after Magento installation

Tags: magento-1.9, database, table, prefix

I need to add table prefix for all the database table.

I know that I can get this option while installing the Magento but **I already installed my magento and I don't want to change the database**,
I just need to add the prefix for all the tables.

I checked lot for this but I didn't get perfect answer for this.

Can anyone help me to do this,

**How can I add prefix to all the tables without any data loss?**

Answer (score 2):

The way I know is to use the following command either one by one:

```
RENAME TABLE tb1 TO my_prefix_tb1;
```

or

```
SELECT Concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' RENAME TO my_prefix_', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_database'
```

as described [here](http://steindom.com/articles/adding-prefix-all-tables-mysql-database)

and then edit the `app/etc/local.xml` and find the tag with name `<table_prefix>` and update it accordingly `<table_prefix><![CDATA[my_prefix_]]></table_prefix>`, and save it.

You have to run these queries directly in the database so please please take a backup first or try on staging.

Comment: @Charlie, please accept the answer if it sorted your issue.

Answer (score -2):

you could delete local.xml (or rename to local.xml.bak) in app->etc which will trigger running through the installer again including the database connection section of the installer where you can enter the prefix name.